# Optimizing Java Cassandra PreparedStatementCache

Tags: java, cassandra

I use org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.support.PreparedStatementCache to cache the preparedStatement.
But it takes a lot of memory.
It looks like if I still use PreparedStatement, the cache never clean, and increase (despite we use the same cql query !!!).
If I stop calling him, the memory will decrease.

My application use springboot /cassandra dse 
We both test in tomcat (windows and linux server, more than 500 req/s).

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.datastax.dse</groupId>
                    <artifactId>dse-java-driver-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>



private final PreparedStatementCache cache = PreparedStatementCache.create();

public Channel findByIdChannel(String idChannel) {

        List<Channel> listChannel = cassandraTemplate
                .getCqlOperations()
                .query(
                        findByIdChannelQuery(idChannel),
                        (row, rowNum) -> cassandraTemplate.getConverter().read(Channel.class, row));
        if (listChannel.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        return listChannel.get(0);
    }

    private BoundStatement findByIdChannelQuery(String idChannel) {
        String cql = "select * from channel where idchannel = '" + idChannel + "'";
        return CachedPreparedStatementCreator.of(
                cache, cql).createPreparedStatement(session)
                .bind();
    }
```

Any recommendation to improve performance (not about making application cache et method level) ?
How can we fix the size of this preparedStatementCache ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Do not make a prepared statement for every idChannel. Create a single prepared statement and bind the id instead and it wont have to create a new one for every query (which is very expensive). like

```
  return CachedPreparedStatementCreator.of(
          cache,
          select()
              .all()
              .from("channel")
              .where(eq("idchannel", bindMarker("idchannel")))
      .createPreparedStatement(session)
      .bind()
      .setString("idchannel", idchannel));
```

Comment: So you mean that PreparedStatementCache doesn't work in this case ? Don't they  look for the preparedStatement in cache by cql before creating the new one ?

Comment: it does but your cql is `select * from channel where idchannel = '1';` instead of (basically) `select * from channel where idchannel = ?;` so each channel 1,2,3.. each has its own prepared statement instead of just 1 for all of them. Thats the entire point of using prepared statements, reduce overhead of parsing statements and values (which is admittedly very small).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have tested 2 case:  - create a single preparedstatement and bind) and using the same cql (like select * from channel where idchannel = '1'). The problem is always there (the PreparedStatementCache takes alot of memory, and it looks like caching the same preparedstatement). Is there any way to config this variable ? Their eviction is by time or by size ? I find nothing about this api of cassandra.

Comment: Springs prepared statement cache is an unbounded never expiring map, if you keep adding new CQL to it you will run out of memory eventually. I wouldnt use spring's wrapper over the driver if you have a choice. I would recommend if using spring to not use prepared statements at all as the positive impact on performance for that table is probably not even measurable anyway.